# Upload File on Server using move_uploaded_file function working on localhost but not on live server

Tags: php

I am using a php file as a web service in android studio to upload a file using the phone camera. When I use the localhost, the files are getting saved in the appropriate folders, however when I use the live server, it does not seem to work. Also I am not able to debug the php file as I don't know how to do it when using it as a web service in an Android App. Below mentioned is the code for my uploadFile.php:

```
<?php
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  include 'db/db_connect.php';
  include 'functions.php';

        $originalImgName= $_FILES['filename']['name'];
        $tempName= $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
        $folder=$_GET['folder']."/";
        $empID = $_GET['empID'];
        $url = "http://www.relyoncts.com/chela/".$folder.$originalImgName;
        if(move_uploaded_file($tempName,$folder.$originalImgName)){
                if($folder=="ppPhotos/"){
                  $query = "INSERT INTO passportphotofiles (empID, pathToFile) VALUES ('$empID','$url')";
                }elseif($folder=="aadharPhotos/"){
                  $query = "INSERT INTO aadharfiles (empID, pathToFile) VALUES ('$empID','$url')";
                }elseif($folder=="panPhotos/"){
                  $query = "INSERT INTO panfiles (empID, pathToFile) VALUES ('$empID','$url')";
                }
                if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){
                  if($folder=="ppPhotos/"){
                    $query= "SELECT * FROM passportphotofiles WHERE pathToFile='$url'";
                  }elseif($folder=="aadharPhotos/"){
                    $query= "SELECT * FROM aadharfiles WHERE pathToFile='$url'";
                  }elseif($folder=="panPhotos/"){
                    $query= "SELECT * FROM panfiles WHERE pathToFile='$url'";
                  }

                     $result= mysqli_query($con, $query);
                     $emparray = array();
                         if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                                     $emparray[] = $row;
                                   }
                                   echo json_encode(array( "status" => "true","message" => "Successfully file added!" , "data" => $emparray) );

                         }else{
                                echo json_encode(array( "status" => "false","message" => "Failed1!") );
                         }

                }else{
                    echo json_encode(array( "status" => "false","message" => "Failed2!") );
                }
            //echo "moved to ".$url;
        }else{
            echo json_encode(array( "status" => "false","message" => "Failed3!") );
        }
  }
?>
```

Line no. 10 when I change it to localhost it works however when I use the live server it stops working:

```
$url = "http://www.relyoncts.com/chela/".$folder.$originalImgName; --this does not work
```

Kindly help...

Thanks

Satish Chandra

Comment: It is probably doing you a favour. There are a number a large security risks in this code

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: You are also allowing a user (using the querystring - GET) to specify a directory name on your server. **I cannot think of a bigger security issue than that right now**

Comment: @RiggsFolly I can: directory listing is enabled on that domain! http://www.relyoncts.com/chela/

Comment: @Satish You need to hire someone else who knows what they’re doing, **now**. You are writing _massively_ insecure code that is opening up you (or your employer) to being exploited within seconds.

Comment: Check permissions on server

Comment: _“it does not seem to work”_ - and how exactly does it “seem” so? What response do you get? You have three different “failed” states there - which one are you running into? Have you enabled proper PHP error logging on the server, and checked what the logs have to say? _“Also I am not able to debug the php file as I don't know how to do it when using it as a web service in an Android App.”_ - well for starters, you could test it _outside_ of that setting - simple HTML form with a file upload field, submitted to your URL, check response … Or via Postman.

Comment: [Don't look that](http://www.relyoncts.com/chela/getUserDetails.php)

Comment: I am very new to PHP coding.  However I am using it just as a webservice for my android app. So I am a bit confused as to how the code is susceptible to sql injection attack when no one will get to know the php file names. I'll be grateful if someone can explain this a bit more so that I will be a bit more safe.

Comment: People could try to reverse engineer your app, they could try and sniff on the network level, … **Security by Obscurity** does not work, it is as simple as that. Whenever your security relies on “yeah, but nobody knows about that …” - you are definitively doing things wrong, and massively so.

Comment: _“I'll be grateful if someone can explain this a bit more so that I will be a bit more safe”_ - SQL injection is an already widely covered topic, you can go read up on what needs to be done about it on your own. The issues with letting users specify file system paths from the outside, falls under the category of _path traversal attacks_, also a keyword you can go read up on.

Answer (score -1):

`chmod 775 /var/www/myfolder`You need to set write access to this folder